# NLog log exceptions with request information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nlog

How is the asp* layout renders for NLog supposed to work?

I have the following setup

**packages.config**

```
<package id="NLog" version="3.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="NLog.Extensions" version="1.0.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**NLog.config**

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="errorlog" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate} [${level}, ${logger}] ${message} ${newline} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline} ${asp-request:serverVariable=String:queryString=String:item=String:form=String}" fileName="c://temp/${shortdate}-errors.log" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorlog"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Logging - with custom message**

```
public class FileExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger<ExceptionLogger>().Error("Woops!", context.ExceptionContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

When logging errors, I get the exception information as expected, but the  `${asp-request...}` part is rendered empty.

If I give the logger the request object for message, it renders the request information as expected:

**Logging - request for message**

```
public class FileExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger<ExceptionLogger>().Error(context.ExceptionContext.Request, context.ExceptionContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

Ain't NLog supposed to pickup on the request information by it self?
If not, how am I supposed to log mye `Woops!`-message?

Comment: Why do you derive from `ExceptionLogger` what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I derive from ExceptionLogger, and register my class as a service in the webapi stack, to get notified of every single exception thrown in the request pipeline so that I can log them through NLog. I could of cause implement IExceptionLogger myself, but I find overriding one method easier. 

Do you think this is related to the problem at all?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there turns out there are multiple things going wrong here....

1. `${asp-request.. }` is for asp. `${aspnet-request...}` is for asp.net
2. When copy-pasting from the docs, you are supposed to substitute datatypes with actual

   ```
   ${asp-request:serverVariable=SOME_ACTUAL_VARIABLE}
   ```
3. When getting the nuget extentions, it helps to get the right one...
   Even though `NLog.Extensions` contains a usefull layout, the one I'm trying to use is in the `NLog.Extended` package...

   ```
   <package id="NLog.Extended" version="3.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
   ```
4. Its not enough to get the nuget package. You'll also have to tell nlog about it...

   ```
   <nlog>
      <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
      </extensions>
      <targets.../>
      <rules.../>
   </nlog>
   ```

so that's that...

I actually ended up with using the `${aspnet-request-summary}` from the `NLog.Extensions`-package, though. It's a little verbose, but that's ok for now.